conditional onClick Event in react
Is something like this, having two functions handling the same event but in a different way common practice?
Or is it more common to seperate and handle the click logic inside one function
const handleClick = (e) => {
    // player sets boat part by clicking on his own tile
    handleClickedTile(e.target);
    console.log(currentGameState)
}

const handleInGameClick = (e) => {
    // player makes attack by clicking on enemies tile
    console.log(currentGameState)
}


<div className="tile" id={coordinate} onClick={currentGameState === "picking boat" ? handleClick : handleInGameClick}>
    <div className="tile-circle"></div>
</div>

I am coding warship and when clicking on a tile, it depends on the gamestate wether or not the player is guessing a field of the enemy player or if the palyer is placing a boatpart at the beginning of the game

I have no idea which is more common. Personally i would do a single function, with the logic inside the function. I choose that because i find it easier to understand. Which one do you find easier to understand? I recommend you use that.

@NicholasTower yeah i see...for me ill probably keep it as it is. I can directly see that there is a seperation and can immediatelly dive into the correct code area - you get what i say?
But as you said, it looks like this really is a personal thing.
Thanks
